# Switching Custom Cells in UITableView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

What I'm trying to achieve is, when a cell in UITableview is tapped, it will expand and display custom cell1, other cells will remain custom cell2.
What I achieved so far is expand the cell, but the custom cell will not change.
After initial investigation, I thought it's the `currentRow` value wasn't changed.  But then I realized if it isn't changed, the row won't expand. Thank you for your help.

Here are the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var currentRow = 0

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.row == currentRow {
            let cell:selectedWeatherViewCell = self.weatherCityTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("selectedWeatherCell") as! selectedWeatherViewCell
            cell.selectedCityLabels.text = city[indexPath.row]
            cell.selectedTempLabels.text = tempertureF[indexPath.row]
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell:cityWeatherViewCell = self.weatherCityTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cityWeatherViewCell") as! cityWeatherViewCell
            cell.cityLabels.text = city[indexPath.row]
            cell.tempLabels.text = tempertureF[indexPath.row]
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
            return cell
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let selectedRowIndex = indexPath
        currentRow = selectedRowIndex.row

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.row == currentRow {
            return 260
        } else {
            return 100
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reload the affected row(s) in order for the cell type to change -

```
var currentRow:Int?

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var reloadRows=[NSIndexPath]()
    if self.currentRow != nil && indexPath.row != self.currentRow! {
        reloadRows.append(NSIndexPath(forRow: self.currentRow!, inSection: indexPath.section))
    }
    self.currentRow=indexPath.row
    reloadRows.append(NSIndexPath(forRow: self.currentRow!, inSection: indexPath.section))
    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(reloadRows, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```